# Conflict mode rolls in UICollectionView inside UIScrollView

Tags: ios, swift, scroll

I'd like to prepare this feature [like this](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=QBwQSeWhU1s&index=1&list=UUiqiwWZF24Lu0sBShpC0z0A). As you can see, it can be horizon scroll (infinite). Also after zoom it can be pan and scroll too.

I use `UICollectionView` to manager content and infinite horizontal scroll. To make zoom I wrap this collection view and bottom view by `UIScrollView`. That is quite perfect except it conflict roll mode between `UICollection` and `UIScrollView`.

I wonder is have any idea for recognize simultaneously roll between them like method `gestureRecognizer(_:shouldRecognizeSimultaneouslyWith:)` in `UIGestureRecognizerDelegate` or maybe any way to handle zoom view like this without use `UIScrollView`. Thank you.